# Relative position to point on picture across screens

Tags: android

I am trying to place textView on specific position related to point on picture (name of pin, which must be editable), I'am facing problem when using different screen size, so I is there any way to make this work.
I tried on some of my phones :

```
-4.3', 720 x 1280 pixels (~342 ppi density) 
-4.0', 480 x 800 pixels, (~233 ppi density) 
-5.1' 1440 x 2560 pixels (~577 ppi density)
```

When I make it work for one device it doesn't work for other two

[I would like to make it like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CrDO.png)

Answer (score 1):

Scale the position of the text field by the same factor you scale up the image by.

```
scaledX=  x_on_disk*image_width_on_screen/image_width_on_disk
scaledY=  y_on_disk*image_height_on_screen/image_height_on_disk
```

Comment: Text fields are positioned using margin, so wouldn't it only affect size of text fields, is there a way to scale margin?

Comment: Set the margins programmatically. Then you can scale them. But you really should not be using text views for this, you should be using a custom view and drawing text over the image. Using multiple views for this is awkward at best

Comment: Yeah, I know its unpractical to use multiple views but I must be able to change textview content

Comment: And a custom view can do that trivially. You can make text views work, it's just very inconvenient